# Is there a step by step guide for setting up a full node on AWS?

Tags: iri-node, aws

It would be very helpful for the community (and the tangle) to have a step by step guide for setting up a full node on AWS. Overview of costs also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found https://github.com/rajivshah3/iri-for-aws

But i didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little update to the above. If you have an Amazon AWS account, this is how to launch full IRI + Nelson node in a matter of 3 clicks. Totally automated!

https://github.com/iotFab/iota-aws-full-node

Answer (score 0):

This is the best manual i've seen, and it is constantly updated:

http://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/master/introduction.html

Answer (score -1):

This may also help you, a detailed step-by-step guide:

http://iota.partners/

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the link into your answer as links tend to rot or change content. Especially such top-level links as provided here.